# call Column that is complex in query

Tags: sql, postgresql, chart.js

can you help me, please?
I have a problem making a chart

I have a query:

```
SELECT to_char((nivo_prelivnik.date1 + nivo_prelivnik.time1), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),round(cast(izch_nivo*100 as numeric), 1),round(cast(debit as numeric), 3) FROM nivo_prelivnik
```

i use

```
for
```

to associate the columns with the chart:

```
 for(var i in data) {
 dateANDtime.push(data[i].to_char);
 izch_nivo.push(data[i].round);
 debit.push(data[i].round);
 }
```

The problem is the names of the columns. I have two different columns that I need to insert names as "round". How I can name the columns with different names?
When I use "izch_nivo" and "debit"  instead of "round" it's not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name the columns by defining column aliases:

```
SELECT to_char((nivo_prelivnik.date1 + nivo_prelivnik.time1), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as col1,
       round(cast(izch_nivo*100 as numeric), 1) as col2,
       round(cast(debit as numeric), 3) as col3
FROM nivo_prelivnik;
```

Note the use of `as` after the expression.  You can then refer to these in the result set.